# What does the *-dev *-dbg and *-utils mean?

Tags: linux, package

When I want to install a library like `libxml2` on ubuntu, I enter `sudo apt-get install libxml2` and enter tab key. There are several names come out such as `libxml2`, `libxml2-dev`, `libxml2-dbg` and `libxml2-uils`.

What are the full name of these suffixes? Which one do I need to install?

Comment: `-dev` denotes development branch, `-dbg` would denote debug version, `-utils` would imply utilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**libxml2-util:** This package provides xmllint, a tool for validating and reformatting
 XML documents, and xmlcatalog, a tool to parse and manipulate XML or
 SGML catalog files.

**libxml2-dev:** Install this package if you wish to develop your own programs using the GNOME XML library.

**libxml2-debug:**:This package provides the debugging symbols for the library and for the utilities provided by the libxml2-utils package. Debugging symbols for the Python modules are not available

Answer of which one you need to install will be based on your need and  what you want to do with package. if you just want to use it then util should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

In general,

**-dev**: Contains the library interface (header files) in case you are developing a program that wants to link to it.

**-dbg**: Contains debugging symbols, which usually just used by developers linking against that software or people debugging the software.

**-utils**: (I'm speaking from my Debian experience) Usually provides some additional command line tools.  It may expose the user to internal features or just provide a CLI.

Having different packages like this is all about removing features and/or accessibility to reduce file size.  This allows for faster downloads and less used disk space.